# Как при клике на блок добавить класс к одному из списка элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите почему при клике на menu__list класс _active добавляется, но потом при клике на li выдает ошибку. А нужно что-бы при клике на menu__list класс _active добавлялся к первому li, и дальше при клике на li класс _active был только у кликнутого li. Строго не судите, я новичек в js. Спасибо

```js
const catalogMenu = document.querySelector('.menu__list');
        const catalogMenuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item');

catalogMenu.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    catalogMenuItem.forEach(item => {
item.classList.add('_active')
                        item.forEach(el => { el.classList.remove('_active'); });
                    });
                });
```

```css
.menu__list{
  padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
}

.menu__item._active{
  color: red;
}

.menu__item{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__list">КЛИК</div>
<ul>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `item.forEach`  --- как ты думаешь, к чему именно ты тут применяешь цикл?

Comment: Ну, каков ответ-то на вопрос?)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю так будет проще.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item');

for (let link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let activeLink = document.querySelector('.menu__item._active');
    if (activeLink) {
      activeLink.classList.remove('_active');
    }
    link.classList.add('_active');
  })
}
```

```css
.menu__list {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu__item._active {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu__list">
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
  <li class="menu__item">LOREM</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: я поправил свою структуру html. Мне нужно что-бы при клике на menu__list к первому li добавился _active, а дальше уже как у вас написано. Но как первое действие сделать я незнаю